# Implementation of Gradient Descent (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with simple implemenation of Gradient Descent algorithm - 
I wrote the following code, just turning the math of GD into a matlab code, but it does not converge. Due to the simplicity of this implementation, I think the I'm missing here very crucial thing about wroking with Matlab.

The goal of this code is to estimate coefficients of linear regression which give us the minimum error. So I loaded some data ('trees.data.txt') and I splited this data into a train set and test set, I want to extract the coefficients using the train and Gradient Descent but unfortunately it does not converge.

This is the iterative equation -
theta = theta - (alpha/m) * ((X * theta - y)' * X)';

Can anyone explain please what is the problem?

My implementation -

```
% Load trees data from file.
data = load('trees.data.txt');
data=data'; % put examples in columns

% Include a row of 1s as an additional intercept feature.
data = [ ones(1,size(data,2)); data ];

% Shuffle examples.
data = data(:, randperm(size(data,2)));

% Split into train and test sets
% The last row of 'data' is the median home price.
train.X = data(1:end-1,1:400);
train.y = data(end,1:400);

test.X = data(1:end-1,401:end);
c = data(end,401:end);

m=size(train.X,2);
n=size(train.X,1);

% Initialize the coefficient vector theta to random values.
theta = rand(n,1);
X = test.X;
y = test.y;

theta_=zeros(size(theta));
delta =0.01; % convergence tolerance
alpha = 0.001; % learning rate
shift = 1000; % big number
iter = 0;
formatSpec = 'iteration: %d, error: %2.4f\n';


while (shift > delta)

   iter = iter +1;
   grad =zeros(size(theta));

   for i = 1:m
       grad = grad + (train.X(:,i)'*theta - train.y(i)).*train.X(:,i);
   end
    %theta_= theta-(alpha*(1/m)*((theta'*X-y)*X')');
    theta_= theta - alpha*(1/m)*grad;
    shift = norm(theta_ - theta);

  fprintf(formatSpec, iter, shift);  
  theta = theta_;
  clear theta_;
end
```

here is the outputs of the first 10 iterations -

```
iteration: 1, error: 151.0904
iteration: 2, error: 46418.0835
iteration: 3, error: 14260790.8611
iteration: 4, error: 4381270296.1843
iteration: 5, error: 1346035405942.4905
iteration: 6, error: 413535616743995.0000
iteration: 7, error: 127048445799311180.0000
iteration: 8, error: 39032448298191028000.0000
iteration: 9, error: 11991740714070305000000.0000
iteration: 10, error: 3684161553354467700000000.0000
```

Comment: It's unclear why you're sure your example should converge?

Comment: First of all that problem was given as homework, so pretty sure it should converge. In addition, this is just a simple linear regression here and the algorithm of gradient descent have to converge in such a problem.

Comment: Homework assignments might have typos or be unverified. Don't rely on this being homework as a reasoning for it being correct (though I'd guess it should be correct). Try solving some simple problem like `x^2+y^2=0` with your algorithm.